# It goes to top of page on using facebook stream.publish method

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using following code for stream Publish, it is working but when this dialog box opens my page scrolls upward and dialog box is down some where so user need to scroll page to see dialog box so why is it hapenning ? how can I correct it?

```
        var attachment = {'media':[{'type':'image','src':image,'href':'<?php echo CANVAS_URL; ?>'}]};
            var action_links= [{ 'text':"Music Mood", 'href': '<?php echo CANVAS_URL; ?>' }];
            FB.ui({'method':'stream.publish','message':message,
                    'attachment':attachment,
                    'action_links':action_links
                });
```

I am using facebook iframe app.

Please reply,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use javascript:void(0); in href of your link

Comment: I am using it in img tag not anchor tag